# Riverpod : Access Provider in initState method

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, riverpod

Trying to read a streamProvider inside initState, but failed. Enlight me please, what am I doing wrong here?

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      final userStream = context.read(userStreamProvider);
      print('user : $userStream'); // user : AsyncValue<Null>.loading()
    });
  }
```

So far, what I found that `context.read(userStreamProvider)` only works inside
`build(BuildContext context)` method

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code works. The problem is, you are not waiting for the user to be loaded.

What you want is probably:

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context.read(userStreamProvider.last).then((user) {
      print('user $user');
    });
    
  }
```

By reading `userStreamProvider.last`, you will be able to *wait* for the user to be loaded. You can then use `.then` or `await` like with all futures.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using latest river pod version . It's not support that context.read function for getting provide values in initstate. How to access provider in initstate using current version of riverpod.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32775821)

Comment: Have you been able to figure this out? I am also trying to access my riverpod provider in initState but context.read is no longer working